# Kurento: multiple mediapipeline mux

Tags: kurento

I am thinking of creating a kms filter which will take input as 2 mediapipeline (A) (B) and output one mediapipeline (C) with Video from 1st mediapipeline (A) and Audio from 2nd media pipeline (B).

I am confused, shall I do this on java level or shall I do this in KMS filter level, Is it even possible to achive this in Java/KMS Filter layer ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create all in one pipeline because different media pipelines cannot share media easily. All can be implemented from the client side (java or js).

You can receive media from two `Endpoints` (for example `WebRtcEndpoints`), `webRtcEp1` and `webRtcEp2` and emit using `webRtcEpOut`. Then just connect them like this:

```
webRtcEp1.connect (webRtcEpOut, MediaType.AUDIO);
webRtcEp2.connect (webRtcEpOut, MediaType.VIDEO);
```

At this point, `WebRctOut` is emiting audio from `webRtcEp1` and video from `webRtcEp2`.

Answer (score 1):

By media pipeline, I take it you refer to media source, right? It is not possible to mix media from different pipelines.

You can check with the `Composite` mixer element. It has never been tested, but it should work. It would be very simple to get the audio from B and the video from A mixed. Let's assume you are getting that media through a `WebRtcEndpoint`

```
Composite composite = new Composite.Builder(pipeline).build();
HubPort hubPortA = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
webRtcA.connect(hubPortA, MediaType.VIDEO);
HubPort hubPortB = new HubPort.Builder(composite).build();
webRtcB.connect(hubPortB, MediaType.AUDIO);
```

`WebRtcEndpoint` creation and negotiation are not shown for clarity.

---

EDIT 1

Thought you might want to mix more that just those two, but as @santoscadenas pointed out, if you only want to mix two streams of different type, you can use directly the `WebRtcEndpoint`. This will also save resources and will scale better, as the `Composite` is quite a hungry thing. Taken from the other answer, and adapting it to your naming conventions, it would be

```
webRtcA.connect(webRtcOut, MediaType.VIDEO);
webRtcB.connect(webRtOut, MediaType.AUDIO);
```

Comment: yes by mediapipeline I mean media source, can you point out any specific method which can be used if I want to try using a kms filter, what should I consider in doing so

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal I think that the composite might work just as you expect. Give it a try right away, and you probably can skip creating your own filter.

Comment: You don't need a composite for this, see my response